# remote desktop connection programatically simulate windows c++

Tags: connection, mouse, simulate

My question is: How you can create same basic functionality with the remote computer, like using the same mouse, so when i take move on my computer that will appear at same moment on remote computer, like on the team viewer. Can anyone explain what is the philosophy behind all remote desktop shared programs, how i can see what I'm done on the remote computer...
Codes & link's will be appriciate too... :)

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the code of [mRemote](http://www.mremote.org/wiki/), a remote connection manager for a number of protocols (RDP, VNC, ssh and more). Maybe that will answer some of your questions?

Cheers,

Sebastiaan